# move object towards or away centre until collision

Tags: java, javafx

I am working in JavaFX trying to centre objects around a point without overlapping. As I am trying to make a word cloud programme.

at first I was trying to place them in a spiral by if the collision occurred
(I have a method for detecting collisions already in my class)

```
if (collisionDetected){
   text.translateXProperty().asObject().setValue((double)80);
}
```

but I couldn't work out how to set a path in a spiral

So I thought generate rand.int x y values and move towards the centre point until a collision is detected and then place the object and move onto the next object in the list. I am not sure how to set a path and increment until the collision is detected. Or would it be better to start with everything from the middle and decide a rand.int within 360 degrees and create a path to the bounds of the scene and increment along that until collisionDetected = false

as in

```
Integer randproperty = rand.nextInt(0, 360);
while(collisionDetected){
    Path path = new Path();
    MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
    moveTo.setX(randproperty);
    moveTo.setY(randproperty);
    path.getElements().add(moveTo);
```

I dont know how to move it across the path until collisionDetected = false.

here are some diagrams linked to imgur to give a visual representation of what I [mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vkca.jpg)

To summarize, I am trying to place objects as close to a centre point without having them intersect. I can check if an intersection has occurred but I am not sure how to then move the text objects to an area where there is no intersection. With pictures linked to imgur as a visual representation.

Thanks

Comment: A. It is not clear to me what **exactly** you are trying to achieve. B. What is you question  (a focused well defined one would be helpful) ? See [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I added a summary, does this help or is it still unclear?